# How can I aggregate init a struct that inherits from a virtual type?

Tags: c++, c++17, virtual-destructor, aggregate-initialization

As per [[dcl.init.aggr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1) I cannot aggregate init a type, if it has (among other things) virtual functions, which includes inheriting from a type with a virtual destructor. However, I'd like to avoid having to write a ton of boilerplate constructors.

MWE:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
  int i;
};

int main() {
  Derived d1{42}; // not allowed in this fashion
  Derived d2{{},42}; // also not allowed
}
```

In my setting I have a lot of types like `Derived` and they are all plain structs with a number of members (not necessarily trivial/pod) **except** for the fact that they have to inherit from `Base`.

Is there a way to avoid having to write `Derived(int i) : Base(), i(i) {}` constructors for all of them?

Comment: *I have a lot of types like Derived and they are all plain structs* - I'd say that none of them are plain structs because they have a base class and it would be better 1) to convert all of them to `class` (to keep `struct` classes C-compatible) 2) to provide a full set of user-defined constructors (probably explicitly prohibiting copy / move and preventing object slicing).

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid writing a constructor. It can be a bit simpler than the one in the question; `Derived(int i) : i(i) {}` will work just fine. The compiler will add the default initialization of `Base`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one solution I could think of, is to exploit the fact that a struct **without** the inheritance above will gladly emit a default aggregate initialiser. So I compose **that** struct together with a templated wrapper type.

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseWrapper : Base, T {
  BaseWrapper(T data) : Node(), T(data) {}
  BaseWrapper() = delete;
  BaseWrapper(BaseWrapper const&) = default;
  BaseWrapper(BaseWrapper&&) = default;
  BaseWrapper& operator=(BaseWrapper const&) = default;
  BaseWrapper& operator=(BaseWrapper&&) = default;
  static T const& cast(Base const& b) {
    return static_cast<T const&>(static_cast<BaseWrapper<T> const&>(b));
  }
  static T& cast(Base& b) {
    return static_cast<T&>(static_cast<BaseWrapper<T>&>(b));
  }
};
```

And since I use the `Derived` types as shared pointers, a small convenience function:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::shared_ptr<BaseWrapper<T>> make_bw(Args&&... args) {
  return std::make_shared<BaseWrapper<T>>(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

Allows us to create objects without the need of a dedicated constructor inside the object:

```
struct Derived { // note the missing : Base
  int i;
};
auto p = make_bw<Derived>(42);
```

This is a bit of a cheaty solution, so a proper answer would still be useful.